# Execute a php script on cPanel

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I am trying to execute a php script present in path `public_html/folder/folder/script.php`.

I've tried these commands but didn't get result

```
curl --silent http://www.folder.domain.com/script.php >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/username/public_html/folder/folder/script.php >/dev/null
```

```
/usr/bin/php -q -f /home/username/public_html/folder/folder/script.php
```

```
php /home/username/public_html/folder/folder/script.php
```

Can anyone correct me where I'm making a mistake?

Comment: Most if not all of these commands should work. What is the output you get when you execute it manually ? does it work as expected ?

Comment: could it be that there is an php error in your script.php? maybe the call are ok, but there is an error preventing the execution of the code ?

Comment: @MostafaHussein I get the expected results when I exeute it manually

Comment: @a.ak then in this case you need to run it as a cron and redirect the output and the error to a file  instead of `/dev/null`. add this to the end of your command `> /home/username/public_html/folder/folder/file.log 2>&1`

Comment: @MostafaHussein I've get the empty file